# Is it bad for SEO to load a page with multiple languages switchable via JavaScript?

Tags: seo, language, shopify

For technical reasons I have to host multi-language support directly in my HTML code and display only the chosen language based on a cookie (user can switch)

```
<span class="language language-fra">BONJOUR</span>
<span class="language language-eng">HELLO</span>

.language{display:none}
.language-fra{display:initial} // IF FRENCH SELECTED
```

This is for a Shopify, thus e-commerce.

Does injecting product description twice in the HTML, in different language, has an impact (positive or negative) on the SEO ?

Comment: How is the selection done?  Is it based on the URL, based on the "accept-lang" header, based on IP address, or does the user have to choose something?

Comment: By default I set to french but user can switch with a small button in the menu and this will toggle language using Jquery

Comment: Google can't crawl that.   When you switch the language, have it change the URL.  Theo's answer is correct.

Comment: Side note (not about SEO): Do you know the `lang` attribute? You should use this instead of `class`. In CSS you can use the [`:lang` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/:lang).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though Googlebot is getting smarted about multi-lingual content and hidden content as well, Google still recommends to:

"Keep the content for each language on separate URLs."(https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192?hl=en).

So, in short: yes, this is likely to negatively impact your SEO.